# Script to copy tables and data from one schema to another in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm sure there's a way to do this but I haven't been able to put the pieces together.

I'd like to:

```
select table_name from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myschema';
```

and then....

```
for each table_name in that list
BEGIN
CREATE table myschemacopy.table_name like myschema.table_name;
INSERT INTO myschemacopy.table_nameSELECT * FROM myschema.table_name;
END LOOP
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Just copy the below Query result and Run it, or you could build dynamic Query.

```
select 'select * into [newschema]. ' + table_name + ' from [myschema].' +table_name
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'myschema'
```

Comment: this isn't exactly correct but it got me close enough so that I could do what I needed to do.  If anyone comes up with something better in the future please let me know.

Comment: what was correct? That u used? What can be a dynamic query?

Comment: Downvoted since you never posted the correct solution

Comment: Something like  select concat('insert  into pcr2.', table_name , ' select * from pcr.',table_name, '; ' )
from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
where TABLE_SCHEMA = 'pcr'

Answer (score 36):

If it's on the same server just a different database, you can use

SOLUTION 1 :

```
   CREATE TABLE newdb.mynewtable LIKE olddb.myoldtable;
```

You can then insert data into the new table from the old using

```
 INSERT newdb.mynewtable SELECT * FROM olddb.myoldtable;

          [or]
```

SOLUTION 2

```
   ALTER table olddb.myoldtable rename newdb.mynewtable
```

Comment: By far the easiest solution to copy a table from schema to another as long as they're on the same server.

Answer (score 5):

It's a little late but having just had to solve the same problem, here's the stored procedure that I came up with, in case it helps someone else:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`whoever`@`wherever` PROCEDURE `copy_schema`(
    IN in_oldDB varchar(256),
    IN in_newDB varchar(256),
    IN in_copyData int(1)
)
BEGIN

DECLARE v_finished INTEGER DEFAULT 0;
DECLARE v_tname varchar(100) DEFAULT "";

DECLARE curTable CURSOR FOR 
SELECT `table_name`
FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES 
WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = in_oldDB
and TABLE_TYPE='BASE TABLE'
;

DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET v_finished = 1;

set @result=NULL;

# Create new schema if it doesn't exist
SET @sql = CONCAT('CREATE SCHEMA IF NOT EXISTS ',in_newDB,';');
PREPARE create_schema FROM @sql;
EXECUTE create_schema;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE create_schema;

# Loop over tables in old schema
OPEN curTable;
clone_tables: LOOP

# get next table name
FETCH curTable INTO v_tname;

# Quit if we're done
IF v_finished = 1 THEN LEAVE clone_tables; END IF;

# Clone the table
SET @sql = CONCAT("CREATE TABLE `", in_newDB, "`.`", v_tname, "` LIKE `", in_oldDB, "`.`", v_tname, "`;");
PREPARE clone_table FROM @sql;
EXECUTE clone_table;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE clone_table;

# Optionally copy data
#select v_tname; # This just gives some feedback in workbench for long-running copies
IF (in_copyData > 0) THEN
    SET @sql = CONCAT("INSERT INTO `", in_newDB, "`.`", v_tname, "` SELECT * FROM `", in_oldDB, "`.`", v_tname, "`;");
    PREPARE clone_data FROM @sql;
    EXECUTE clone_data;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE clone_data;
END IF;

# Result message
SET @result = IFNULL(CONCAT(@result,',',v_tname),v_tname);

END LOOP clone_tables;

# Close cursor
CLOSE curTable;

# Print result message
SELECT CONCAT("Copied the following tables from ", in_oldDB, " to ", in_newDB, ": ", @result);

END
```